# Ocultar Ruta de enlace de descarga en PHP o javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy haciendo un gestor de descargas en PHP, mediante el que un usuario puede bajar un archivo.

lo que intento es lo siguiente
En vez de pasarle la ruta directa al archivo (www.dominio.com/ftp/archivo.rar) pásale, www.dominio.com/descarga.php?id=3
este en el gestor de descargas cuando haga clic en propiedades para ver de donde se baja, solo verá www.dominio.com/descarga.php?id=3 y no la ruta absoluta al archivo.

lo que me intereza es ocultar la ruta de descarga o crear una ruta temporal

gracias de ante mano.

buscando una solucion encontre esta que esta muy fasil pero no logro inplementarla al 100%

```html
 <?php
switch($id) {
case '':
header ("Location: http://Mi-pagina.com"); // esta sera la pagina que aparecera al abrir el archivo por defecto
 break;
case 'descarga1': // Este sera el nombre que le pondremos al id del archivo
header ("Location: ./archivos/descarga1.zip"); // esta es la ruta del nombre del archivo a descargar
break; 
default:
header ("Location: http://Mi-pagina.com"); // esto al igual que el primero es el header por default que aparecera al acceder al archivo directamente osea redirigira para alla si quieren accesar al archivo directamente desde el navegador
} ?>
```

asi quedaria el enlace de descarga
http://mi-pagina.com/descarga.php?id=descarga1

la primera ves me funciono bien pero en otras pruevas no descarga el archivo  en cuestion y no tengo idea que parte del codigo esta mal .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es obtener el nombre real del archivo a partir del parámetro que pasaste en la URL. Para eso usas el mecanismo que prefieras: te sugirieron recorrer el directorio y comparar con un hash, pero otra solución podría ser buscar en una base de datos:

```
$idArchivo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'); // Esto lee $_GET['id'];
$file = $db->get_var("SELECT nombre FROM archivos WHERE id = ". $idArchivo);
```

Supongamos que los archivos están en un directorio cuya ubicación tienes en la variable `$dir`. Ahora puedes usar esta lógica para forzar la descarga del archivo:

```
$filename = $dir . $file;
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Si en vez de forzar la descarga quieres que el archivo se abra en el navegador (es útil si es un archivo `jpg` o `pdf`) debes reemplazar `application/octet-stream` por el **mimetype** correspondiente al tipo de archivo.

Comment: gracias amigo realmente no quiero usar base de datos  prefiero usar una carpeta para almacenar los harchivos

Answer (score 2):

Una solución puede ser usar un hash como identificador. Por ejemplo, **archivo.rar** hasheado (bcrypt) queda como:

```
/descarga.php?id=$2a$06$I3wuZYJKUDK.yYwTy9yzv.CfCI14CMurChOev8mbUhJ1MmgXzlzQe
```

Y en PHP iterar la lista de archivos para saber qué archivo coincide (por nombre) con el hash:

```
$hash = '$2a$06$I3wuZYJKUDK.yYwTy9yzv.CfCI14CMurChOev8mbUhJ1MmgXzlzQe';    
$path = './public/archivos/';
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
$file = '';

foreach($files as $file) {
  if (password_verify($file, $hash)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    readfile("{$path}/{$file}");
    break;
  }
}
```

**Nota:** `scandir` también lista directorios, así que, si tienes subdirectorios dentro de la carpeta de los archivos a descargar, asegúrate que `$file` no sea un directorio.

Comment: hola me podrias dar un ejemplo de su uso ya que no estoy muy familiarizado con php

Comment: tengo que crear un harchivo "descarga.php" con el codigo que tu pones please una explicacion

Comment: Claro, debes crear un archivo `descarga.php`. Allí iría el código que pongo y los archivos a descargar en `/public/archivos`. El ejemplo que puse es para descargar el archivo *archivo.rar* (`/public/archivos/archivo.rar`).

Comment: $hash = $_GET['id']; id es el nombre de el harchivo a descargar supongo pero tu codigo me da error

Comment: en esta linea "foreach($file in $files) { "de error en php

Comment: Sí, es un error de tipeo. Es `as` en lugar de `in`. He actualizado el código de mi respuesta.

Comment: ultilisando tu php con el nombre index.php me da muchos errores

Comment: ¿Muchos? Es curioso cuando el código solo tiene unsa cuantas líneas. Si quieres más ayuda, **menciona que errores tienes**, porque así es ayudarte a ciegas.

Comment: estoy ulilizando wampserver para prueva y este codigo <?php

 
$hash = $_GET['serie.txt'];
$path = '/archivos/';
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
echo $path;
echo $files;

foreach($file as $files) {
  if (password_verify($file, $hash)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile("{$path}/{$file}");
    break;
  }
}
?>en un hachivo index.php y tira muchos errores no los pongo por que no me deja este editor espero me ayudes

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions He actualizado el código ya probado en local. Funciona como se espera.

Comment: lo acabo de probar y me da error en esta linea "if (password_verify($file, $hash))"   Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in C:\wamp\www\descarga\index.php

Comment: Actualiza tu versión de PHP. Repito, **el código está porbado por en mi máquina** usando PHP7. Actualiza tu versión.

Comment: gracias lo se pero "password_verify" esta indefinido

Comment: Amigo, **no necesitas definirla** porque es una [función](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) que es parte de la API estándar de PHP. Si no está disponible en tu versión quiere decir que estás usando una PHP 5.4 o inferior, lo cual no te recomiendo para nada porque es **obsoleta**.

Comment: gracias amigo pero si subo este php a un version de php4 que no es php7 me dara el mismo problema y eso quiero evitar para no preocuparme por la vesion de php. igualmente te doy la gracias

Comment: En ese caso investiga un poco y reemplaza dicha función para que compares hashes sha-x. Así lo haces compatible con versiones obsoletas.

Comment: ok amigo gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @GustavoGarcía seguro que bcrypt es determinístico? Al menos mcrypt sé que no lo es, la salida de password_hash con el mismo seed puede ser distinta en distintos momentos del tiempo

Comment: La salida es distinta siempre. De hecho, puedes poner cualquier hash en `?id=` que te genere bcrypt para *archivo.rar*  y `password_verify` funcionará igual, porque el hash obviamente es de un solo sentido. De eso de encarga el algoritmo de bcrypt.